# parallel connection issue in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to read data files from a directory using foreach. But it is giving me an error. It works on my office machine, but does not work at home. Both machines have 4 cores, check output at the bottom. Here is the code

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("D:/Test")
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

c1<-makeCluster(4, outfile = "debug.txt")
CE<-clusterEvalQ(c1, .libPaths(""))
registerDoParallel(c1)

print(paste0("Cores = ",detectCores()))
file.names <- dir(pattern ="h00|B00")
output<-list()

output<-foreach (i=1:4) %dopar% {
       read.table(file=file.names[i])
}

stopCluster(c1)
```

I am getting error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "cannot open the connection"

[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `foreach` call with a `for` loop? Always a good idea to debug this way if you suspect the cluster as causing a problem.

Comment: It works with for-loop but does not work with foreach. I find in debug file that it does not find file in the directory. But I checked file.names that contain correct files names loaded from the directory.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `foreach` backend, but it might be best to send absolute file paths to each node, rather than relative paths. You can do this by including `full.names=TRUE` in your `dir` call... Relative paths (which you're using here) rely on the working directory being retained by all nodes, which may not happen (again, I'm not sure).

Comment: I found the solution but did not understand, why the previous code works on my office machine but not at home machine. In addition to suggested by rosscova, I also need to include directory path. It should be dir("D:/Test",pattern ="h00|b00",full.names=TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("D:/Test")
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

c1<-makeCluster(4, outfile = "debug.txt")
CE<-clusterEvalQ(c1, .libPaths(""))
registerDoParallel(c1)

print(paste0("Cores = ",detectCores()))
file.names <- dir("D:/Test",pattern ="h00|b00",full.names=TRUE)
output<-list()

output<-foreach (i=1:4) %dopar% {
      read.table(file=file.names[i])
}

stopCluster(c1)
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to this answer, so that others can see what you learned, and what helped you solve the problem.

Comment: As you commented above, it requires to add absolute file path mentioned in above comments. Solution works, but I have no explanation, why it works on one machine but not on other.

Comment: See if `output <- foreach (i=1:4) %dopar% { list(pwd = getwd(), files = dir(), info = file.info(file.names[i])) }` returns what you think it should.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in parallel operations in R, and I can't help with why you've got different behaviour on different machines (are they the same OS, with the same versions of R and R packages?). My understanding is that functions like `foreach` start up multiple R sessions in the background, each of which acts as a "node" to compute a subset of the operations. In your case, each of these nodes needs to find files to feed `read.table`, so I personally think it's good practice to pass full file paths whenever using parallel processes.

Using `dir` with default parameters returns relative file paths (ie: relative to your current working directory) meaning that you need to stay in your current working directory to correctly refer to them. I'll explain by first setting my working directory to my Desktop:

```
desktop.path <- "~/Desktop"
setwd( desktop.path )
getwd()
# [1] "/Users/ross/Desktop"
```

Now we can get the path to a ".txt" file, which sits on my Desktop, in a few ways. First, with default parameters.

```
file.default <- dir( pattern = "txt" )
file.default
# [1] "CW_denseCloud_LowestQual_withGCPs.txt"
```

Notice there's nothing in that link to show where the file is, we're relying on our current working directory to find it, which is fine for now.

```
file.exists( file.default )
[1] TRUE
```

But if we end up in another working directory, we'll lose the file:

```
setwd( "~" )
file.exists( file.default )
# [1] FALSE
```

If we pass the parameter `full.names = TRUE`, we get more than the file name itself, but it's still a relative path, which doesn't help:

```
setwd( desktop.path )
dir( pattern = "txt", full.names = TRUE )
# [1] "./CW_denseCloud_LowestQual_withGCPs.txt"
```

What will help is passing a complete path to `dir` as well, such that `dir` is effectively looking at the file relative to the root directory, rather than from the current working directory:

```
file.full <- dir( path = desktop.path, pattern = "txt", full.names = TRUE )
file.full
# [1] "/Users/ross/Desktop/CW_denseCloud_LowestQual_withGCPs.txt"
```

Now we've got a complete path to the file, rather than a relative one, meaning that we'll find this file, regardless of where we're sitting (working directory):

```
file.exists( file.full )
# [1] TRUE

setwd( "~" )
file.exists( file.full )
# [1] TRUE
```

Now, even if the working directory isn't passed properly to each processing node, they can still find the files they need.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and makes sense. I am using the same setup on both machines with same version of R, the only difference is in the OS (Win7 Vs win10).